# browser can't see my national language

Tags: html, browser

I have the code in html

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>ერთი ორი სამი </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

so when I run this browser instead of words i'm getting some unknowing letters

Comment: Add `lang="<language name>"` to HTML tag and check.

Comment: Also use meta character set (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp)

Comment: make sure you set the charset to utf-8.

Comment: charset worked thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your `<head>` section, specify that the charset is `UTF8` using `<meta charset="UTF-8">`:

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>ერთი ორი სამი </h1>
</body>

</html>
```

[Official documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Add `lang="<language name>"` to HTML tag and check.

You can refer to http://www.mathguide.de/info/tools/languagecode.html for referring

Also make sure that related font-family is also present in your website (for support to that language if it is not web-safe font).

And as mentioned by Spudley, include charset as well. I missed it in first place :-(